# Leftovers and Chillul Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, cooking-bishul

Suppose you were to cook much more food than you ended up needing on a given shabbat. Would it constitue chillul shabbat (or be disrespecting shabbat in any way) to either:

A) eat the leftovers on Sunday thus not cooking for a second consecutive day?

Or

B) freeze the leftovers after Havdalah and reheat as the next week's Shabbat meal?

Comment: Why should there be a difference? Many people use left overs from shabbat during the week.

Comment: Suppose it's special dishes or ingredients you only eat on Shabbat

Comment: Not only can't I envision any problems whatsoever, but, it is almost impossible not to have left-over, practically. It would also be *bal tashchit* to dispose of good left-overs, anyway. Furthermore, I know numerous frum families that intentionally cook extra so that there will be left-over for the following week. Lastly, what do you think mamy kosher take-out places are serving on Sunday nights?

Comment: I assume by cook you mean prepare (like put dressing on a salad) as cooking would be an issur deoraysa and the food would be forbidden. Also when you make food on shabbos (or yom tov) you can only make for that day. But if you made, and there was extra that's fine.

Comment: Good point, @mroll, the food is being cooked (full-on bishul) prior to sunset on Friday, the issue is it ends up being more than is needed over the course of the sabbath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have made a neder to use this particular food only on shabbat, then you would have to keep the neder. However, if you have set it aside for shabbat, then you have only determined that you will use it for **that** shabbat. Once shabbat is over, the food is still usable. As an example you can see [Shamai HaZakein Buying for Shabbos All Week](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73059/shamai-hazakein-buying-for-shabbos-all-week/86086#86086) where Shamai Hazakein (Beitzah 16a) set aside food for shabbat and replaced it if he found better food and ate it during the week.

Similarly, once food is *left overs* it is now of a lower quality than what would be made fresh the next week and can be eaten during the week (like Shamai did).

Comment: This seems to answer A but not B.

Comment: @DanF Since I explain how A is possible, then B is not required. The question was asking that if A is not allowed, then would B be allowed or would the food have to be discarded.

Comment: I think the key point is that leftovers are *lower quality* @Dan so lo longer fit for the Sabbath table...if a king or the president of the country I live in (not the US so no need to complicate things) ever pops by for a meal he's not getting reheated leftovers

Comment: @JoshK I got that. Though, even without the *neder*, I think that if you make a lot of food and you leave the left-overs specifically for next Shabbat, I don't think it's "significantly" lesser quality. It's certainly a significant step up from eating "weekday" food on Shabbat. Busy people can't always make fresh food, weekly. That does put to question, perhaps, a recent practice of *mishmar* and kosher take-outs serving chulent on Thursday night and having the left-over for Shabbat.

Comment: That's the heart of the matter, @DanF. Upon further reflection, many stewy Shabbat type dishes are better on the 2nd or 3rd day after cooking. I think I'll get some psak on the issue

Comment: @JoshK I would like to hear what someone says. But, perhaps, the question is bigger. You're question focuses on left-overs from Shabbat. What I'm (and you, maybe) wondering is at what point is your cooking designated for Shabbat? There is a "mitzvah" to taste the Shabbat food on Friday, and to start preparing on Friday. However, if you prepare on Wed. having in mind that this is Shabbat food, but you decide to eat some of it now, have you nullified the whole process of Shabbat preparations?

Comment: .@Danf I doubt that as your tasting is part of the preparation and making sure that it is good

Comment: @Danf Note that Shamai prepared from the beginning of the week. Part of preparing is tasting to make sure.

Comment: @sabbahillel There may be a difference between tasting and making a meal out of it.