# Downgrading clothing from Shabbos to Weekday

Tags: halacha, shabbat, kedusha-holiness, chol-weekday

Is there anything wrong with buying a new hat (or suit, shirt, pants, socks, shoes, skirt, dress) for Shabbos, and then taking one's old Shabbos hat (or suit, shirt, pants, socks, shoes, skirt, dress) and downgrading it for use on weekdays?

On one hand, this seems to be the Middah of Shammai Hazaken (Beitzah 16a):

> תניא אמרו עליו על שמאי הזקן כל ימיו היה אוכל לכבוד שבת מצא בהמה נאה אומר זו לשבת מצא אחרת נאה הימנה מניח את השניה ואוכל את הראשונה
>
> It is taught in a baraita: They said about Shammai the Elder that all his days he would eat in honor of Shabbat. How so? If he found a choice animal, he would say: This is for Shabbat. If he subsequently found another one choicer than it, he would set aside the second for Shabbat and eat the first. He would eat the first to leave the better-quality animal for Shabbat, which continually rendered his eating an act of honoring Shabbat. (Sefaria)

On the other hand there is a concept of :מעלין בקודש ואין מורידין and therfore it would be inappropriate to take something designated for Shabbos and downgrade it to weekday. (Perhaps the case of Shammai is different since the food was not yet actually used on Shabbos, just designated for Shabbos and הזמהה לאו מילתא although, if so, perhaps having Shabbos leftovers during the week would be a problem...)

Comment: When confronted with בל תשחית on the other hand (what will you do with those clothes anyway - throw away?), downgrading is a far better option.

Comment: Related to your point of הזמנה לאו מילתא היא in relation to that Gemara of Shammai HaZakein: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73059

Comment: @DonielF Interesting. It looks like the answer there attempts to address my question at the end, but I don't really understand their proof.

Comment: @Al How do you understand the concept to wear special clothing on Shabbos; is it not a fulfillment of זכור את יום השבת לקדשו? That makes this a case of אתי עשה ודחי לא תעשה potentially.

Comment: @Silver Why don't we take this discussion over there? The one who wrote that answer hasn't been so active recently, but maybe he'll chime in.

Comment: @Loani Ya, I just noticed that now

Comment: @DonielF IIRC, the Gemmorah says בגדים נקיים not "different clothes" to start with. Not many could afford a special shirt for Shabbos. So even a new shirt is not מקודש for Shabbos, it honors Shabbos but not מקודש.

Comment: @AlBerko It does say בגדים נקיים. But it also says לא יהיה מלבוש החל כמלבוש השבת. Shabbos 113a learns this from וכבדתו.

Answer (score -1):

The idea of "[מעלין בקדושה ולא מורידים](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F)" (see [WIKI's summary in Hebrew](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%91%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A9_%D7%95%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9F)) is not universal, it applies only to a limited set of holy objects, Mitzvos and people:

1. תשמישי קדושה (Religious articles) like Teffilin, Torah scroll, etc.
2. Channukah lights - we go from 1 to 8
3. Kohen Gadol and King's wife.

As Shabbos clothes are not "Religious articles", this rule does not apply to it. EDIT: *as most people don't designate those clothes specifically for the Mitzva (of Nevi'im) of honoring Shabbos.* You can wear those clothes for other events, family Simchas, etc. I suspect that if you openly and verbally specified that those items serve solely the purpose of that Mitzvah, you should consult your Rabbi for downgrading to weekdays or even for wearing those to Simchas.

How about a pie that you cooked for and ate on Shabbos can you finish it on a weekday?

Comment: I see the Wiki lists those examples, but does the wiki bring a source that it ONLY applies in these situations?

Comment: @Silver No, you're invited to edit. It only refers to when the Halacha forbids it, but since the rule is too general, you can always apply it to other areas like if you bought a Tzitzis for your elder son he can't transfer it to his siblings.

Comment: Without a proof that this *only* applies in these cases, I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Also, you left out the original source for מעלין בקדש, that the pans used by the 250 men in Korach's assembly had to be used for the Mizbeiach (Menachos 99a). So Wiki is definitely not an exhaustive list.

Comment: @DonielF That was one time, and WIKI speaks of Halocho.

Comment: That’s the source for the principle! How can you just say it doesn’t count?

Comment: @DonielF What do you call a proof? Why the community WIKI is not proof? It might not be perfect, but it is a good source.

Comment: @AlBerko Wiki doesn’t demonstrate that this list is exhaustive.

Comment: @DonielF I didn't discuss the source, I listed in what cases it is applied Halachicly. If you can think of more case, you would shake my answer, but till then?

Comment: @DonielF Why don't you do exactly that to answers of others, when somebody gives one source, why don't you jump "it is not exhaustive"?

Comment: How about that we put Tallis on before Tefillin (SA OC 25:1)? Order of tying Tzitzis (Menachos 39a)? That the head of a Sanhedrin can’t be demoted to a regular judge (Rambam, Hil. Sanhedrin 17:9)? That a Sefer Torah can’t be made into Tefillin, nor Tefillin into Mezuzos (Yerushalmi Megillah 34a)? The list goes on and on.

Comment: @AlBerko I would if I saw an answer where that complaint is valid, but I haven’t seen another such answer where I could say that.

Comment: @DonielF Those all are subsets of 1, 2, 3. Read carefully, it says "1. objects, 2. Mitzvos and 3. people". I didn't say those specific cases, I said those SETS.

Comment: Okay, let’s go with that. How are בגדי שבת not תשמישי מצוה and a part of your category #2, since, as I established in the comments to OP, they’re derived from וכבדתו?

Comment: @DonielF I'd suggest that if you specifically designated it for Shabbos Mitzvah, like you said "those trousers are specifically for Shabbos Kavod mitzvah", you're probably right and it will be forbidden to downgrade it, but until then... who's מקדיש clothes for shabbos kavod mitzvah?

Comment: @Al But you don’t say that in this answer. You say that Shabbos clothes aren’t Mitzvah objects and the rule doesn’t apply at all.

Comment: @DonielF Yes just because most people dont designate them for Mitzvah. OK, I'll clarify that in the answer.

Comment: @DonielF I inserted that clarification